# Adding field which, depending on direction field value, gets value from previous or next row/feature in another field?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I am having difficulty getting to grips with arcpy and cursors. What i aim to do is the following: Depending on the direction specified in **Test** I wish to update the **Target** field. If it is *forward*, the Target should receive the Value of **AP** from the next row/feature. In this example for the first feature, the **Target** would be 2. Aditionally, if the direction specified is *backward* the **Target** field should receive the value from the previous row. To make matters worse, the **AP** and **Target** fields are strings (and converting them is not an option as the data provided in ususally alphanumeric), so simply adding and subtracting 1 is not possible.

[image]

what i have so far:

```
i = 0  
lastvalue = []  
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InFC, [Direction, AP]) as cursor:  
    for row in cursor:
        if Direction == "forward":
            newField = AP[row+1] ## here id like to reference the next value somehow
        else:
            newField = AP[row-1] ## here id like to reference the previous value
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: I would add code if i had any to begin with. It is mostly failed attempts that i have promptly deleted.

Comment: @BERA's right - all that we try to avoid is becoming a "code writing service": https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115

Comment: fair enough, I am new to python. coming from R where indexing is a breeze i find this pretty challenging

Comment: What happens when you run the exact code snippet that have presented?  If it gives an error then telling us the exact error message including line number is what we are after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cursor can only look at one row at a time but you can use two: Store all AP values in a list using a SearchCursor. Then use indexes to fetch values from the list and update using UpdateCursor. `counter` is keeping track of current row and used as index to fetch values from AP list. I dont know what you want to do at first/last row when you cant go backwards/forwards, im using current row value:

```
fc = 'contour'
fields = ['AP','Test','Target']

AP_list = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields[0])]
listlength = len(AP_list)

counter = 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] == 'forward':
            if counter == listlength-1:
                print 'Last row, cant go forward! Using current row value'
                value = 0                
            else:    
                value = 1
        else:
            if counter == 0:
                print 'First row, cant go back! Using current row value'
                value = 0
            else:
                value = -1
        row[2] = AP_list[counter+value]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        counter+=1
```

[image]